# Shared code between server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a web game in JS, using Node on the backend. To make things easier, I'm trying to have the server and client share as much code as possible. I do it by having the `Server` object and `Client` object inherit the same `Game` object.

For the most part it works well: I have shared functions in the `Game` object, server specific functions in `Server`, and client specific functions in `Client`. But for certain cases I just don't know what to do: for example, if for a given, shared function (say `update_physics()`) the server might be doing some specific stuff that the client isn't supposed to do (like checking if a game element is dead), how do I fit that in the code?

I'm going in this direction, but it kind of defeat the point of having separated files (shared/server/client):

```
function update_physics () {
  // do stuff for both client and server

  if (this.is_server) {
    // do server specific stuff
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler/better way to achieve what I'm trying to?

Comment: In meteor.js which is also isomorphic they do similar check `if(meteor.isServer)` so I think that this is the way to go

Comment: you're right, I should have looked at Meteor, they're literally trying to do the same